# when to use FileProvider in android studio ...totally beginner programmer

Tags: java, android, class, oop

i am trying to get knowledge in android studio to make apps so if found this code snippet .

```
enter code herestatic final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
// Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    // Create the File where the photo should go
    File photoFile = null;
    try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Error occurred while creating the File
        ...
    }
    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
    if (photoFile != null) {
        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                                              "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                                              photoFile);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
    }
}
```

}

I understand almost all the code but i just confused with "FileProvider" !!
what is it ? and when we use it ?

Comment: [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of your code, it was used to create the actual file (of the photo) and  getting the `handle`...

```
    // Create the File where the photo should go
    File photoFile = null;
    try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Error occurred while creating the File
        ...
    }
```

..then using the handle to get its URI(location on the phone storage)

```
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"com.example.android.fileprovider", photoFile);
```

...and then taking the photo. Saving to that location(the URI)

```
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
```

Pretty much well-commented in the code you provided

Comment: thank you for all this answer . i really get new info. from you and can you tell me what is the _Uri_ used for ?

Comment: The URI is the the [Uniform Resource Identifier](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986). It's a compact sequence of characters that identifies an abstract or physical resource....it can be used to name a resource or locate it (as it is used above). It's similar to a file path or web or ftp address to a particular item...only that in this case it gives the location of the file to which you want to save the photo that was taken. Otherwise (Google the rest)[https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Auri]...and head on over to (Android Developers)[https://developer.android.com]/index.html